# Configure NGINX for multiple rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am running an instance of redmine on the root dir. I am trying to set up another rails app on the same server.

I tried with the location directive, but it just redirects to 404 page of redmine.

here's my config

```
passenger_enabled on;
        root /var/data/redmine/public;

        location /app2{

                root /var/data/app2/start;
        }
```

Comment: may be this might help? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-and-unicorn-multiple-rails-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working through unicorn.